# Value of variables and Time Complexity of this Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

[image: Algorithm]

Questions:

1. p and q value at end of this algorithm execution
2. Time Complexity of this algorithm

My Answer:
[image: My Answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inner loop increments `p` a number of times equal to the base-2 logarithm of `n`. As the outer loop executes `n` times, the final value of `p` is `n.lg(n)`.

Now the second loop increments `q` a number of times equal to `lg(p)`, where `p` takes the values `k.lg(n)`, or `1, 2, 3, ... n` times `lg(n)`. The final value of `q` is `lg(n!)+n.lg(lg(n))`.

The time complexity follows easily, as the number of operations is proportional to the number of incrementations of `p` plus those of `q` plus some negligible overhead. Finally, `Θ(lg(n!)) = Θ(n.lg(n))`.

---

Note that these are only approximations, as the true number of iterations is the floor of the logarithm, not the logarithm.

Comment: I haven't understood how you calculated q value as lg(n!)+lg(lg(n))

Comment: @RajIshu: Σlg(k.lg(n)) = Σlg(k)+Σlg(lg(n)) = lg(n!)+n.lg(lg(n))